# Array of worksheet variable

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

As per documentation, I can define array of worksheets like below

```
Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
```

But what happens if my worksheets are dynamically created and pointed by pointer variable like below? How can I make an array of them so that I can loop through them to do same activity?

```
Dim tempsheet1 As Worksheet
Dim tempsheet2 As Worksheet

Set tempsheet1 = Sheets.Add
Set tempsheet2 = Sheets.Add

Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array(tempsheet1, tempsheet2)) ' Doesn't work
For Each msheets In sheetsArray
    With msheets
        DO SOMETHING
    End With
Next msheets
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you should specify sheet names in Array, change

```
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array(tempsheet1, tempsheet2))
```

to

```
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array(tempsheet1.Name, tempsheet2.Name))
```